# Angular js: Remove certain element from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I built buttons with ng-repeat:

```
<button ng-repeat="alphabet in alpha" ng-click="checkAlpha()" value="{{alphabet}}">{{alphabet}}</button>

$scope.alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
```

The question is how to remove only the button that is clicked. I used ng-hide in button, but then all the buttons are gone. 
What is the best way to do that? 
Thanks

Comment: ng-click="checkAlpha($index)" and provide implementation in checkAlpha() method to handle the deletion by index :)

Comment: You can use $index. There is a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/SX4gE/11/

Comment: Good fiddle, I've updated it to match the question :) Upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <button ng-repeat='alphabet in alpha ' ng-click="checkAlpha($index)" value="{{alphabet}}" id="{{$index}}">{{alphabet}}</button>
</div>
```

JS:(similar)

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    //lets create array from a string.
    $scope.alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split("");

    $scope.checkAlpha = function(index) {
        $scope.alpha.splice(index, 1);//remove
    }
});
```

FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/SX4gE/20/

Comment: The `remove()` is not necessary and no *Angular* way. Removing the character from the array is sufficient to remove the button (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SX4gE/15/)).

Comment: @Holybreath Thank youu :) is it possible, to all the other buttons to stay in their position(absolut) after one button is clicked?

Comment: Updated the fiddle ;) http://jsfiddle.net/SX4gE/20/ , if it's fine by you that ng-repeat is used on the div containing the buttons.